# What happens if in Gatsby, instead of using GatsbyLinks, I use <a> tags?

Tags: javascript, gatsby

What happens if in Gatsby, instead of using GatsbyLinks provided by Gatsby to link to my own pages, I use `<a>`-tags? What would be wrong with that?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that. You'll be only missing out on enhancements which built-in component provides : )

Answer (score 1):

The Link component is used to navigate between internal pages of a Gatsby site instead of using regular anchor (a) tags. The benefits of using Link instead of a regular anchor are the following:

Gatsby will intelligently prerender the linked-to content
State can be passed to the linked-to page
Custom styling or a custom class can be added to links when the active page corresponds with the link.